# Facing issue in nebular datepicker

Tags: angular8

Facing issue in nebular date picker And Getting date as a day before. Ex. If I select 2020/05/05 and checks in database the date the goes to 2020/05/04.

Comment: time zone difference?
* I don't know angular...

Comment: it could be.but any  specific syntax to set timezone